# LLVM OPT not giving optimised file as output.

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

The man page for `opt` says: "It takes LLVM source files as input, runs the specified optimizations or analyses on it, and then outputs the optimized file or the analysis results".

My Goal: To use the inbuilt optimisation pass `-dce` available in `opt`. This pass does `Dead Code Elimination`

My Source file `foo.c`:

```
int foo(void)
 {
   int a = 24;
   int b = 25; /* Assignment to dead variable -- dead code */
   int c;
   c = a * 4;
   return c;
}
```

Here is what I did: 
1. `clang-7.0 -S -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.ll` 
2. `opt -dce -S foo.ll -o fooOpt.ll`

**What I expect** : A .ll file in which the dead code (in source code with the comment) part is eliminated.

**What I get**: fooOpt.ll is the same as non optimised code foo.ll

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758987/using-llvm-opt-with-built-in-passes) SO answer, but I didn't get optimised code. 
Am I missing something here? Can someone please guide me on the right path.
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the .ll file generated by clang, it will contain a line like this:

```
attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone sspstrong uwtable ...}
```

You should remove the `optnone` attribute here. Whenever a function has the `optnone` attribute, `opt` won't touch that function at all.

Now if you try again, you'll notice ... nothing. It still does not work.

This time the problem is that the code is working on memory, not registers. What we need to do is to convert the `alloca`s to registers using `-mem2reg`. In fact doing this will already optimize away `b`, so you don't even need the `-dce` flag.

Comment: Ok, so for any other optimisation option I want to check, say `-constprop`, should I use `-mem2reg` as a default option?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Yes, many optimizations will only work after local variables have been converted to registers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir.