# LLVM's opt does not load plugin (.so), and does not output any error

Tags: compiler-construction, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

From what I have gathered, to use opt to run a compiler pass on an .ll file, I can load a plugin first, and then run the pass using the plugin:

`opt -load=./myPass.so -help`

`opt -myPass myProgram.ll -o myOptimizedProgram.ll`

However, when I run the first command, the newly loaded plugin does not show up in the -help output. Opt doesn't print any error message, so I'm not sure how to start to look for a reason why.

If anyone can suggest a way to begin to track down a reason for this error (eg, is there any way to make opt print out any usable error message), I would greatly appreciate that as well.

I have seen the following solutions, which did not work for me:

[LLVM OPT not giving optimised file as output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092340/llvm-opt-not-giving-optimised-file-as-output)

[Using LLVM opt with built-in passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758987/using-llvm-opt-with-built-in-passes)

It also might be helpful to know that, when I try to run the pass using clang like so:

`clang++ -Xclang -load -Xclang ./myPass.so myProgram.ll -o myOptimizedProgram.ll`

it prints out an error message just fine.

*Edited some misused words.